# Why are these functions recurring?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

If I execute step 1 of the below function twice (each of which in turn triggers steps 2,3,6), I want to then be able to execute step 4 *once* without it recurring the same number of times that I executed step 1 (step 4 triggers steps 5 and 6).

Why does step 4 (and its following functions) repeat itself the same number of times I execute step 1 (and its following functions)?

```
  $(function(){

    var selected = [], clickHandler;

    var el = document.getElementById("user_search_tags");
    el.addEventListener("click", returnSelected, false);

    // step 1
    $('#people_search_mobile').change(function() {
      console.log(1);
      $('li a', $('#suggestions')).bind('click.autocomplete', clickHandler);
    });

    // step 2
    function clickHandler() {
      console.log(2);
      selected.push($(this).text());
      returnSelected(selected);
      queryMaker(selected);
    }

    // step 3
    function returnSelected(selected) {
      console.log(3);
      tagRemover(selected);
    }

    // step 4
    function tagRemover(selected) {
      $('.search-tag').click(function(){
        console.log(4);
        $(this).hide();
        spliceAndSearch($(this).text(), selected);
      })
    }

    // step 5
    function spliceAndSearch(removed, selected) {    
      console.log(5);
      selected.splice(selected.indexOf(removed), 1);
      queryMaker(selected);
    }

    // step 6
    function queryMaker(selected) {
      $('#uquery').val(selected);
      $.get(this.action, $('#people_search_mobile').serialize(), null, 'script');
      $('#uquery').val('').focus();
      console.log(6);
      return false;
    }

  });
```

Here is a summary of my console log (with steps as numbers):

1
2
3
6
1
2
3
6
4
5
6
4
5
6
3

Thank you.

**SOLUTION**

$(function(){

```
var selected = [];
var clickHandler;

$('#people_search_mobile').change(function() {
  $('li a', $('#suggestions')).bind('click.autocomplete', clickHandler);
});

$('body').on('click', '.search-tag', tagRemover);

function tagRemover() {
  $(this).hide();
  console.log(selected);
  selected.splice(selected.indexOf($(this).text()), 1);
  queryMaker(selected);
}

function clickHandler() {
  selected.push($(this).text());
  returnSelected(selected);
  queryMaker(selected);
}

function returnSelected(selected) {
  var saySelected = function() { alert(selected); }
  return saySelected;
}

function queryMaker(selected) {
  $('#uquery').val(selected);
  $.get(this.action, $('#people_search_mobile').serialize(), null, 'script');
  $('#uquery').val('').focus();
  return false;
}
```

});

Comment: Could you make a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clickhandler(2) calls returnselected(3) which calls tagRemover(4) which calls spliceAndSearch(5) which calls queryMaker(6)

tagRemover will only log a 4 if it gets a search-tag match, so your console log is slightly deceptive

You've bound step1 (and thus step4) to a 'change' function so it is almost inevitable they are going to run the same number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Step 4 doesn't actually execute the logging and hiding and splicing, but rather hooks those up to the `click` event of your `.search-tag` element(s).

From that perspective, look at your code again, and find out what order you're supposed to be running these in.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a global variable called `once` and set it equal to 1.  Then, make an `if` statement around `tagRemover(selected);` in step 3 that checks if `once == 1`.  Then, once inside the if statement set `once = 0` so that it doesn't execute again.